# Can't run PhpStorm on Windows 7 (32 bit), getting this error: Could not find or load main class com.intellij.Main

Tags: phpstorm

Can't run PhpStorm on Windows 7 (32bit), getting this error:

> "Could not find or load main class com.intellij.Main"

Comment: How far did you get through the install of phpstorm? sounds like u have not installed properly. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/installing-and-launching.html might help

Comment: Have you installed 32-bit JDK? PhpStorm comes with 64-bit version of JDK. And offers to download and install 32-bit version separately (it's a check box in installer -- on a step when you select what shortcuts to install etc) -- have you used it?